# Codeigniter - DataTables warning (table id = 'DataTables_Table_0'): Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, hmvc

I'm trying to populate values from the database into a PHP page, however, I receive this popup error message whenever the page loads the data.
The populated values are all correct but this popup never goes away. Thank you very much for your help in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1P16.png)

**Error Message**

DataTables warning (table id = 'DataTables_Table_0'): Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row...

**PHP**

```
<div class="box-content">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Count</th>
              <th>Color</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php
            $count = 0;
            foreach($query->result() as $row) {
              $count++;
              $delete_url = base_url()."store_item_colors/delete/".$row->id;
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?= $count ?></td>
                <td class="center"><?= $row->color ?></td>

                <td class="center">
                  <a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?= $delete_url ?>">
                    <i class="halflings-icon white trash"></i>Remove Option
                  </a>
                </td>

              </tr>
              <?php
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

**Controller**

```
    <?php
class Store_item_sizes extends MX_Controller
{

function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}

function update($update_id) {
  // only those people with an update_id for an item can get in.
  if (!is_numeric($update_id)) {
    redirect('site_security/not_allowed');
  }


  // fetch existing options for this item
  $data['query'] = $this->get_where_custom('item_id', $update_id);
  $data['num_rows'] = $data['query']->num_rows();

  $data['headline'] = "Update Item Sizes";
  $data['update_id'] = $update_id;
  $data['flash'] = $this->session->flashdata('item');
  $data['view_file'] = "update";
  $this->load->module('templates');
  $this->templates->admin($data);
}
```

**Database (MySQL)**

Num of columns: 3
- id: PRIMARY KEY, INT
- item_id: INT
- color: VARCHAR(120)

Comment: can you please code snippet of your controller?

Comment: Please format it in the code block. ;) hard to read here

Comment: I'm checking please wait

Comment: Place semicolons after these two variables $count and $delete_url. Try and let me know

Comment: Thanks, these codes are actually from a tutorial by David Connelly - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rV4m1i82k94&list=PLBEpR3pmwCayNcTCUWlUToK4qIQfFQCCm&index=16

Comment: Just did it but didn't make a change.

Comment: I think you have to change it a little bit let me do it for you. hope that will work

Comment: why are you not using model?

Comment: I am using a model. I edited the HTML format and now it is not giving any errors. Thank you very much for your answers :)

Comment: Glad to help :)